# Error in creating an Order by the Customer while checking out

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

**Environment:**

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/makeOrder/9/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.8 "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HARSHA\Documents\sdp-2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HARSHA\Documents\sdp-2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\HARSHA\Documents\sdp-2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HARSHA\Documents\sdp-2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HARSHA\Documents\sdp-2\website\views.py", line 232, in makeOrder
    'fuel'         :fuel,

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /makeOrder/9/
Exception Value: local variable 'fuel' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You forgot to add your code and write what have you tried so far to fix that error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.